# Fixed size string get / set

Tags: c#

I have problem with fixed size string in struct and get / set methods for databinding.

My struct:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
struct MyStruct
{
    public int Var1 { get; set; }
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
    public string Var2;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
    public string Var3;
    public int Var4 { get; set; }
};
```

When i set { get; set } for Var2 and Var3 i get error:

> error CS0592: Attribute 'MarshalAs' is not valid on this declaration
>   type. It is only valid on 'field, param, return' declarations.

How me make set / get methods for Var2 / Var3 and **not change struct size**?

Comment: Someone have other variants?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `string` is a C# type, and can't be mapped to a C type. Try marshaling the strings privately as `char[]`s, and converting them to strings in C# (no marshaling). You'll also need to change the `MarshalAs` to represent that you'll be marshaling arrays, not strings.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
struct MyStruct
{
    public int Var1 { get; set; }
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 32)]
    private char[] _Var2;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 32)]
    private char[] _Var3;
    public int Var4 { get; set; }

    public string Var2 {
        get {
            return new string(_var2);
        }
        set {
            this._var2 = value.ToCharArray();
        }
    }
    public string Var3 {
        get {
            return new string(_var3);
        }
        set {
            this._var3 = value.ToCharArray();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: its not change struct size?

Comment: I forgot to address the struct size part; you can put some logic in the setters to trim the input `string` down to 32 chars or add spaces to expand to 32 chars before writing the values to the `char[]`s.

Comment: "The problem is that string is a C# type", like that no bcz i make char[] Var2 / Var3 and i get same error (i mean with get / set using)

Comment: I have an exact instance of this kind of thing at work; I can look up my exact answer and get it to you when I go in tomorrow. Sorry for the delay...

Comment: Ok, I saw what I'd forgotten. Be sure to change the `MarshalAs` type; also added the full `get`/`set` bodies for your convenience. Hope this helps!

Comment: Marshal need for fix size of string, but if use char array with fixed size - i cant normaly use this members and struct bcz its unsafe method...